# Show that $\sum_{n}\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis

I have problem to show the convergence of $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}.$$
I tried d'Alembert and integral criterion, but it's not conclusive. I also try to bound it by $\frac{1}{n^\alpha }$ for $\alpha >1$, but without success.

Comment: For sums containing $\log$'s it's useful to remember than $\log(n)$ grows slower than any power of $n$ so for any $\epsilon > 0$ we will have $\log(n) < n^\epsilon$ for large enough $n$. You can prove this by computing $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^\epsilon}$ using L'Hopital for example. Once you know this then it's easy to bound the summand.

Comment: @Winther Could you tell me why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^\epsilon}=0$ for positive $\epsilon$ imply $\log n< n^{\epsilon}$ for large $n$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $A_n/B_n \to 0$ tells you that $A_n$ will be much less than $B_n$ (in absolute value) for large $n$. This follows from the definition of a limit: If $A_n/B_n \to 0$ then for any $\epsilon' > 0$ there is some large $N$ such that if $n > N$  we have $|A_n / B_n - 0| < \epsilon'$. Taking $\epsilon' = 1$ gives you this particular inequality, but as you can see you will also eventually have $\log(n) < 0.0001n^\epsilon$.

Comment: @Winther Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$\log(n)\leq \sqrt n.$$

$ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One has, integrating by parts,
$$
0\le \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\le\int_1^N\frac{\log(x)}{x^2}\:dx=1-\frac{\log (N)+1}{N} \to \color{red}{1},
$$ as $N\to \infty$, using the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Use the cauchy condensation test. The series converges iff the folowing  series
converges, namely
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}2^n\frac{\log(2^n)}{(2^n)^2}.
=\log(2)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{2^n}\tag{1}
$$
which converges since 
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n =0}^\infty nx^n;\quad (\lvert x\rvert<1
)
\tag{2}
$$
(set $x=1/2$). Hence the original series converges.